# How to keep alive connect to server via socket when app in background mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sockets

How to keep alive connect to server via socket when app in background mode

Comment: Please refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032745/how-to-handle-socket-connections-events-when-app-is-in-background

Answer (score 0):

[setKeepAliveTimeout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622989-setkeepalivetimeout)
 is deprecated and works on Xcode 7.3, if app is compiled against iOS9 SDK. If you compile app on the latest Xcode (8.3.3 at the moment) it will not work. I tried to create the framework with `setKeepAliveTimeout` on the Xcode 7.3 (against iOS9 SDK) and use it in the app on the Xcode 8.3 (iOS10 SDK) -  it didn't work too.